# VirtualDocumentRoot and CNAME

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, cname-record

We have a apache setup that uses VirtualDocumentRoot.
This is out vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vsweb005.[domain].local
    ServerAlias *.*.*.vsweb005.[domain].local
    ServerAlias *.*.*.[domain].co.uk
    ServerAlias *.*.*.[clientdomain].co.uk

    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/client/%3/%2/%1

    SetEnv FX_ENVIRONMENT staging
    SetEnv FX_CORE_PATH /var/www/master
    SetEnv FX_CLIENT_PATH /var/www/html/client

    <Directory /var/www/html/client/*>
           Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks +Multiviews
           Allowoverride All
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With"
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

            RewriteEngine On

            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^config\.(.*) [NC]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !component\.json [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /component.json?$1 [QSA,L]

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
            RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=51]

            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The URL we use is "x.y.z.[domain].co.uk" which works correctly and maps to the correct folders. 
Our client will use their own URL "a.[clientdomain].co.uk" and create a CNAME record to map to ours.

this does not map to the correct folders. is there anyway for this to work?

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got this set up to listen to `*.*.*.[clientdomain].co.uk`, not `*.[clientdomain].co.uk`.

`*.*.*.[clientdomain].co.uk` won't match `a.[clientdomain].co.uk`, since there aren't enough `.`s in the host name.